# Monitor.Exit() sometimes hangs

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I seem to have a concurrency problem when using Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit. Sometimes my code hangs on the following Monitor.Exit statement:

```
public void EndInit()
{
    Monitor.Enter(this.lockObj);
    this.initCount--;
    if (this.initCount == 0) {
        this.IsInitializing = false;
        this.IsInitialized = true;
        this.OnInitialized();
    }
    // sometimes, this Exit will never return ...
    Monitor.Exit(this.lockObj);
}
```

There's only one other place, where my **lockObj** is used:

```
public void BeginInit()
{
    Monitor.Enter(this.lockObj);
    this.initCount++;
    this.IsInitializing = true;
    this.IsInitialized = false;
    Monitor.Exit(this.lockObj);
}
```

And that's how I declare this sync object:

```
private readonly object lockObj = new object();
```

I'm tearing my hairs off to find out, what it is going on here, but with no success. I'd expect `Monitor.Enter()` to block until my sync object gets released, but why is `Monitor.Exit()` blocked? I can't find any explanation for this behavior in **MSDN** either.

**Note** I can't reproduce this behavior, it occurs rather randomly (well, I know that "random" is not the correct wording).

Any ideas or helpful hints are highly appreciated!

Thorsten

Comment: If possible you could replace the `Monitor.Enter` / `Monitor.Exit` combination with a `lock() { }` block. What would happen if an exception is thrown before the `Monitor.Exit` call ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm making an answer from my previous comment. Because you should have used a `try finally` construct to correctly have the `Monitor.Exit` being called when an exception occurrs in the `OnInitialize()`.

So the code would then become

```
public void EndInit()
{
    Monitor.Enter(this.lockObj);
    try
    {
        this.initCount--;
        if (this.initCount == 0) {
            this.IsInitializing = false;
            this.IsInitialized = true;
            this.OnInitialized();
        }
    } 
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(this.lockObj);    
    }
}
```

The same goes for the second method.

It can also be written like this then

```
public void EndInit()
{
    lock(this.lockObj)
    {
        this.initCount--;
        if (this.initCount == 0) {
            this.IsInitializing = false;
            this.IsInitialized = true;
            this.OnInitialized();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

A very good explanation on threading written by Joe Albahari can be found [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). It is a well deserved read.

**Edit 2 (for completeness)**

Also as stated by  Damien_The_Unbeliever, there is an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498(v=vs.110).aspx).

this will only work for .NET 4 and up. The code using the monitor would then become:

```
public void EndInit()
{
    bool lockAcuired = false;
    try
    {
        Monitor.Enter(this.lockObj, ref lockAquired);
        this.initCount--;
        if (this.initCount == 0) {
            this.IsInitializing = false;
            this.IsInitialized = true;
            this.OnInitialized();
        }
    } 
    finally
    {
        if(lockAquired)
            Monitor.Exit(this.lockObj);    
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to manually implement the `lock`, you should use the variant that uses the two argument [`Enter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498(v=vs.110).aspx) *enclosed* within the `try` block. It was introduced by .NET 4 (I believe) to deal with the edge case of an exception being thrown between `Enter` having returned and the `try` block starting (in which case `Exit` isn't called, in your current variant)

Comment: While writing this question and digging deeper into my own (old) code, I just figured out the same (potential) source for this issue:  `OnInitialized()`  may throw an exception which currently goes unhandled (and even unrecognized). I moved this call out of the sync block and added  `try` / `catch`  . Future will show, if this remedies the problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I updated my answer for the .NET4 version. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Probably saved me a lot of time that would be wasted on finding simpliest working solution. Thank you.